# mobile web app loading issue

Tags: web-applications, mobile-safari, loading

I'm making a mobile web app and have discovered a weird thing. when opening the app from the home screen the loading time is double compare to just entering the url manually. My startup splash image is what's displayed while it's loading.

This is not just my app. I've seen it on others to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Apple uses the "old" JavaScript engine for Home-Screen-Bookmarks (iOS < 5). That is one improvement that is coming with iOS5.